# How to Call C++ Native Properity from C#

Tags: c#, c++, native-methods

I'm not that good in C++
but,..
For example I have this

```
#define GETSomthing_API  __declspec(dllexport)
extern GETSomthing_API int nGetSomthing;
```

And the method I want to import like this

```
GETSomthing_API  int GetSomthing(const char* szConfigPath, char *A, int B)
```

How Can I call this from C# ?

Beside,
I think my problem is with the parameter type (const char* ) in C++ side, what is the equal type in C# for it! const char*

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't that be `extern "C" int nGetSomeThing(void);` in C++ for a function (to be used as a static method in C#)?

Comment: You can use `unsafe` keyword? Look at this: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf8fb136-c2a8-417d-8e06-3d20b035ec1b/cc-pointer-function-dll-calling-from-c-application?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: I can't change the C++ code, and extern "C" is not exists there :(.

Comment: I think my problem is with the parameter type (const char* ) in C++ side, what is the equal type in C# for it! const char*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to call C++ code from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407616/how-to-call-c-code-from-c-sharp)

or

[Calling C++ function from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041160/calling-c-function-from-c-sharp)

Using:  [DllImport("xxx.dll")] xxx.dll is compile by C++

Hope this help.

Comment: I think my problem is with the parameter type (const char* ) in C++ side, what is the equal type in C# for it! const char*

Comment: Your Function: GetSomthing(const char* szConfigPath, char *A, int B). I think: char* szConfigPath in C++<==> string szConfigPath in C#, but i don't know what is the "A" variable?, Can you give me some value of  the "A" variable.

Comment: my problem was somthing else, still didn't understod it but it worked when i used #ifdef __cplusplus

Comment: Hi, I'm not a progamer with c++, but you can find somthing about the #ifdef __cplusplus in here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/  , and Does your function worked?. Sorry, i'm trying to learning English.If you don't understand, please tell me.:D

Comment: No! your so good... Thanks BTW, :)  and yes I fixed my problem finally :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways for calling into native code from C#. The easiest is probably to use `P/Invoke`.
Say your function is like :

```
extern "C" int nGetSomeThing(void);
```

and it is compiled into a YourDllName.dll file, you can use P/Invoke to directly call into the unmanaged code in the following way from C# code :

```
public static class interop
{
    [DllImport("YourDllName.dll")]
    static extern public int nGetSomeThing(void);
}
...
interop.nGetSomething() // call to the native function
```

Refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28VS.71%29.aspx.

If you have a lot of functions with complex signatures, you should probably go for an interop layer in C++/CLI.
Refer : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes

Comment: I think my problem is with the parameter type (const char* ) in C++ side, what is the equal type in C# for it!  const char*

Answer (score 0):

I just added __cplusplus check and it worked!

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
```

extern "C" {

## endif

```
GETSomthing_API char* GetAgentId(const char* szConfigPath, char *szA, int ASize);
```

## ifdef __cplusplus

}